# Count values greater equal to sthg from multiple rasters at once pixelwise in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, cell-statistics

I have 36 TIFF rasters for the same spot, overlapping 100% and having the same dimension.

My goal is to create a result raster where each pixel represents the number of values where a condition is fullfilled.
For example using `count`, if `value >= 5` then the algorithm should check the same pixel in each layer of the 36 rasters; then writes it. `min` should be `0` if no condition is fullfiled and `maximum` should be `36` if all layers fullfill the condition at same pixel.

Is there such algorithm or tool to do it in QGIS? I am using QGIS 3.28.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `Raster > Raster calculator`, use the following formula:

```
("Raster1@1">5)  +  ("Raster2@1">5) + ... +  ("Raster36@1">5)
```

This will return a value between 0 and 36 for each pixel, with a contribution of 1 every time the condition is met on one raster's pixel.

Notes:

- Make sure to select all the raster layers before launching the Raster Calculator if you want them to appear in the Raster Bands
- Parenthesis are important otherwise it returns no result.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, that is a great idea!